# SQL query for woocommerce

Tags: sql, database, woocommerce, tags

I built a woocommerce sql query to list all products with their important values.

Here my query:

```sql
SELECT 
p.ID,
p.post_type as Art,
p.post_title AS Produkt,
p.post_excerpt AS Beschreibung,
t.name AS Produzent,

MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = 'faktor' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as Faktor,
MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = 'produzentenvergleich' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as PV,
MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = 'einkaufspreis' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as EP,
MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_regular_price' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as RegPreis,
MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = 'variationspreis' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as VarPreis,
MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_purchase_note' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as Liefertermin,
MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND pm1.meta_value = 'instock' then 'Ja' END) as lieferbar,
MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = 'produzenten_bestellvorgabe' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as Vorgabe,
MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = 'durchschnittsgewicht' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as ø Gewicht, 
MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_alg_wc_pq_min' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as Min_Menge,
MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_alg_wc_pq_max' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as Max_Menge,
MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_alg_wc_pq_default' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as Def_Menge,
MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_alg_wc_pq_step' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as Step_Menge,
MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_unit' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as Unit,
MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_sale_price_label' then pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as Preis_Label


FROM KtS4szE8u_posts p 
LEFT JOIN KtS4szE8u_postmeta pm1 ON pm1.post_id = p.ID
LEFT JOIN KtS4szE8u_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.object_id = p.ID
JOIN KtS4szE8u_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id 
JOIN KtS4szE8u_terms AS t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id

WHERE p.post_type = 'product' AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND substring(p.post_title,1,12) <> 'Mindermengen' and substring(p.post_title,1,9) <> 'Glaspfand' and substring(p.post_title,1,16) <> 'Mitgliedsbeitrag' and substring(p.post_title,1,10) <> 'Barzahlung' and substring(p.post_title,1,1) <> '€' and substring(p.post_title,1,9) <> 'Umbuchung' and  substring(p.post_title,1,7) <> 'Gutschr'
GROUP BY p.ID,p.post_title
```

This query works fine but I need also a column with the product tag.
How can I add this to my query?

Thank you
Siegfried

Comment: I think that you need to join once more `term_relationships AS tr2`, `term_taxonomy AS tt2` and `terms AS t2` for `'product_tag'` taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry
I found my mistake.

```
JOIN KtS4szE8u_term_taxonomy AS tt2 ON tt2.taxonomy = 'product_tag' AND tt2.term_taxonomy_id = tr2.term_taxonomy_id 
JOIN KtS4szE8u_terms AS t2 ON t2.term_id = tt2.term_id
```

Now it works fine.
Thank you once more.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**